# PhoneGap app PHP/MYSQL database query returns different results on iPad and iPhone

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a really annoying problem. When a "pageshow" event occurs, an external web service type DB query is executed, returning data to be displayed on the users screen.

On the iPad (2) this works perfectly, but on the iPhone (5) the result returns the exact same as the first result that was returned when the app first ran. If the app on the iPhone is uninstalled and re-installed again, the query picks up the correct data, but then keeps returning this no matter what I change in the database. Its as if the data is being cached somewhere. BUT.. .I am using jQuery's ajax() function, and I have alert()'s in the success handler of the ajax request, stating that the query was a success, but still produces the wrong data in this success.

Is there any way the iPhone 5 caches the entire AJAX request and just assumes the same data is being sent and received?

Thanks
James

Comment: did you set the cache setting to false in your ajax() call ?

Comment: Yep that was the problem :) thanks